# Mocha failed assertion causing timeout

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm getting started with mocha testing framework with NodeJS. Success assertions working fine but if the assertion fails, my test timeouts. For asserting I've tried Should and Expect. For example (async code)

```
  it('should create new user', function(done){
    userService.create(user).then(function(model){
      expect(model.id).to.be(1); //created user ID
      done();
    }, done)
  });
```

Here the if model id is not 1 then the test timesout instead of reporting failed assertion. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like is how current implementation is. https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/278

Answer (score 17, accepted):

expect is throwing an error that is being caught by the promise.  Adding a catch condition that calls done fixes this.

```
it('should create new user', function(done) {
    userService.create(user).then(function(model) {
        expect(model.id).to.be(1); //created user ID
        done();
    }).catch(function(e) {
        done(e);
    })
});
```

Comment: If you're using mocha 1.18 or better, danvk's answer below is better.  I almost missed seeing that answer myself, so I'm commenting here for visibility.

Answer (score 18):

Shawn's answer works, but there is a simpler way.

If you return the Promise from your test, Mocha will handle everything for you:

```js
it('should create new user', function() {
  return userService.create(user).then(function(model){
    expect(model.id).to.be(1); //created user ID
  });
});
```

No `done` callback needed!

Comment: Promise support [was added](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/HISTORY.md#1180--2014-03-13) in Mocha 1.18, i.e. after this question was first asked.

Comment: Great! Im going to accept Shawn's answer as danvk pointed out :)

Comment: Thanks.  This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `done` is never called. Besides `then`, you may also need an `else` to handle the failure.