# Test assertion inside a hook (Mocha + Chai)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

This is my assertion:

```
    it('test 1 - 200', (done) => {
        receiver.on("get_payload", (payload) => {         
            expect(payload).to.be.an("object");
            expect(payload.text).to.be.a("string").equals("text-sender");
            done();
        });
        sender.emit("get_payload", { receiver: receiver_id, text: "text-sender" })
    });
```

Here the receiver gets the event. The problem is when an assertion fails I get a timeout instead of actual cause.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245611/mocha-failed-assertion-causing-timeout) that this is because assertion throws an exception and execution never reaches done().

What happens to that exception I am not sure. If Mocha catches it or ignores it.

Now in my case do you suggest making a promise chain for  assertion or what other pattern seems suitable?

Answer (score 0):

This must be done like this:

```
    it('test 1 - 200', (done) => {
        receiver.on("get_payload", (payload) => {
            try {
                expect(payload).to.be.an("object");
                expect(payload.text).to.be.a("string").equals("text-sender");
                done();
            } catch(error) {
                done(error);
            }
        });
        sender.emit("get_payload", { receiver: receiver_id, text: "text-sender" })
    });
```